# Drag drop on mobile devices using some code that translates event (code included), but normal events are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, dom-events

I am using the below code to allow for touch drag and drop on my website. However, while the parts of my code which have drag/drop functionality work, on an iPhone, I cannot scroll or move the page in anyway. I can drag & drop, but regular iPhone touch functionality is gone!

I have found the below snippet in several Stack Overflow responses so I am wondering if there is a workaround for this. I want to be able to drag & drop on both web and mobile.

My dragging code (just a list):

```
$(function() {
    $(".drag_me ul").sortable();
});
```

code for touch events:

```
function touchHandler(event)
{
 var touches = event.changedTouches,
    first = touches[0],
    type = "";

     switch(event.type)
{
    case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
    case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
    case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
    default: return;
}
var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                          first.screenX, first.screenY,
                          first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                          false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
event.preventDefault();
}

function init()
{
   document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);    
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say I use this on a web app of mine for the iPad. All other events work fine, it must be an error in your code. For reference: http://www.midemos.com/demos/iphone/touch/?/iphone/touch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on the same problem and think I just licked it. I removed the guts of touchHandler and use them to populate the callback that binds the event listeners only to the children of `<div id='stage'>`. Below is my code using jquery. Hope this helps!

```
function init(){


 $("#stage").children().bind('touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', function(){
    var touches = event.changedTouches,    first = touches[0],    type = ""; 
    switch(event.type){    
      case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; 
    break;    
      case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; 
    break;            
      case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; 
    break;    
      default: return;
    }

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                      first.screenX, first.screenY,
                      first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                      false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);
    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Comment: Of course, it would be better to make the selector string ("#stage") an argument to init, or pass init() an array of selector strings and do the binding in a loop for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You are preventing the default scroll functionality with this line of code:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Since this event object is tied to the document, all native scrolls are disabled.

If you want to allow scrolling the page natively then add your event listeners to a descendant of the document element (that way if the user scrolls in a region other than the sortable container they will be able to scroll the page normally).

Change:

```
function init()
{
   document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);    
}
```

To:

```
function init()
{
   $('#sortable_container').bind('touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', touchHandler); 
}
```

Comment: ah.. ok makes sense. so would this #sortable_container be the id of some div perhaps where I want to allow the touch events..?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea. So if the user scrolls on the `div#sortable_container` then the dragging event handler will fire, otherwise they will be able to natively scroll the page.

Comment: I have 2 places on my site that I want to allow dragging. So I have:

<div id="dragregion" class="drag1">...</div>
<div id="dragregion" class="drag2">...</div>

I tried to call the bind on #dragregion but none of the dragging works now :/

Comment: I also changed the ID to unique IDs and still, I can't seem to get this working. There is no touch based dragging in or outside of the div.